# Preg replace image class using php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a image with class 'attachment-fullslideshow'. The code is

```
<img class="attachment-fullslideshow" src="demo.jpg">
```

I would like to replace the class from 'attachment-fullslideshow' to 'attachment-fullslideshow quote'.

Please suggest.

Comment: do you want to do in php or jquery?

Comment: Isn't it better to use jQuery ?

Comment: It's better to use Jquery like `$(".attachment-fullslideshow").addClass("quote");`

Comment: I know jquery will be better but I have to use php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$str = '<img class="attachment-fullslideshow" src="demo.jpg">';

$str = str_replace('class="attachment-fullslideshow', 'class="attachment-fullslideshow quote', $str);

//Result: <div class="attachment-fullslideshow quote">...</div>
```

Or with regular expressions:

```
$str = '<img class="attachment-fullslideshow" src="demo.jpg">';
$str = preg_replace(':class="(.*attachment-fullslideshow.*)":', 'class="\1 quote"', $str);
//Result: <div class="defaultClass myClass">...</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could also

```
$html = '<img class="attachment-fullslideshow" src="demo.jpg">';
$test = preg_replace('/class="(.*?)"/s', 'class="newclass"', $html);
echo $test;
```

outputs

```
<img class="newclass" src="demo.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks David. It helps a lot.